# How to import a device in SCCM

Tags: sccm, sccm-2007

I am new to **SCCM.** I am trying to import a device in **SCCM** and how we can assign an IP and Hostname to that device.
Is there any possibility to add an IP to a device through CSV file while importing device?

Comment: Is this a question about programmatic import? If so in which language?
As to the second question: SCCM is no DHCP it does not manage IPs. It will get the information about which IP a client has as part of it's inventory automatically, you would only import MAC (or GUID)

Answer (score 0):

To import devices/computer objects in SCCM you need to specify computer names as well as MAC address or SMBIOS GUID of devices. You can do this for one or multiple computer objects e.g. via SCCM console (Assets and Cpmliance -> Devices -> Import Computer Information) or via Powershell Cmdlet Import-CMComputerInformation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/configurationmanager/import-cmcomputerinformation?view=sccm-ps) or VBS or C# (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/configmgr/develop/osd/how-to-import-a-new-computer-into-configuration-manager)